# How to install composer through cloud function in GCP?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-composer

How to install composer through cloud function in GCP ? did not find appropriate documents or examples on web. I am want a cloud function to install or create a composer environment.

I did not find or saw any of the examples

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents, Installing Composer within a Cloud Function isn't the standard approach, reason being it would take time to create the env with specific configs and post which also moving the DAG etc to the env.

something worth looking at would be to Triggering a Cloud Composer DAG from a Cloud Function.